# Getting related object's ID without fetching it from the database (Play framework)

Tags: hibernate, playframework

Say I have these two models:

```
public class City extends Model
{
    @ManyToOne
    private Country country;
}

public class Country extends Model
{
}
```

I have a City object and want to know the related Country's ID. I could fetch from the database by doing `city.getCountry().getId()` but that seems very wasteful. How can I just get the ID (stored in the database table as `country_id`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think fetchType=LAZY is what you need. It creates a proxy-object for the country and it should not do any queries by requesting the id.

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Country country;
```

But you also need do mark your id-getter in Country.

```
public class Country extends Model
{
    @Id
    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

If you don't want do change your id-annotations you can also use this workaround:

```
  Serializable id = ((HibernateProxy) country).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getIdentifier()
```